# How Can I Use A 2 Dimensional Array As X and y Coordinates Using Loops?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

Haha... kinda a weird question, but it's for a video game I am making. I need to be able to load maps from an array of text maps. So for this map I have:

```js
//MAPS
var map = new Array();

map[1,1] =  "####################";
map[1,2] =  "####################";
map[1,3] =  "####################";
map[1,4] =  "####################";
map[1,5] =  "####################";
map[1,6] =  "####################";
map[1,7] =  "####################";
map[1,8] =  "####################";
map[1,9] =  "####################";
map[1,10] = "####################";
map[1,11] = "####################";
map[1,12] = "####################";
map[1,13] = "########BBBB########";
map[1,14] = "####################";
map[1,15] = "####################";
map[1,16] = "#############BBBB###";
map[1,17] = "###BBBB#############";
map[1,18] = "####################";
map[1,19] = "####################";
map[1,20] = "BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB";
```

Okay... so the "#" character is meant for no objects to placed, basically nothing will be spots where I put them when I run it in the end.

The "B" characters are going to be block objects I've made. So, I instinctively threw in for loops:

```js
//READING FROM MAPS
var block = new Array();

for (var o = 0; o <= 19; o ++) {
 for (var i = 0; i <= 19; i ++) {
  var n = map[1,o].charAt(i);
  if ( n == "B") {
  block[blockCount] = new Object((n*32),(o*32),32,32,"IMAGES/block.png");
  blockCount += 1;
  }
 }
}
```

Okay seemed a little easy to whip up, but of course, errors. Game won't run in the browser. I don't exactly know what to do if I can't do something similar to this. Any ideas/solutions to my problem, if the code itself isn't stupid?

Thanks for your time!
-Smy

Comment: What kind of erros? How do the text-maps work? Multiple lines of # and B's?

Answer (score 1):

The multi-dimensional notation you are using with a map ({}) does not work in Javascript.
When you write :

```
map[1, 12] = 'some string';
```

you are in fact doing :

```
map[ (1 , 12) ] = 'some string' ;
```

using the , operator, which returns the last evaluated expression.
Here (1, 12) === 12, so here it's just like you typed :

```
map[12]= 'some string' ;
```

(There may be some other errors, just wanted to underline that one.)

Comment: Ahh I see. So how could I write the map differently?

Answer (score 1):

The following shows how you could structure the the 2 dimensional array display.
In this link:https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/hunger-games/6623296612990976
[
This is a KhanAcademy program that shows how to use array maps to display something.][1]

```
var s = 'Possible spawn points';
var hunger_map = [ // This Is the Map
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,s,0,0,s,0,0,s,0,0,s,0,0,s],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,s,0,0,s,0,0,s,0,0,s,0,0,s],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,s,0,0,s,0,0,s,0,0,s,0,0,s],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    ];

var displayMap = function(themap){
for (var i = 0; i < themap.length;i++){ // I loop through the array like this
    for(var f = 0; f < themap[i].length;f++){
        switch(true){
            case themap[i][f] === 0: //Empty square
                fill(255, 255, 255); //color of the square
                break;
            case themap[i][f] === s: //Blue square
                fill(0, 255, 242); //color of the square
                break;
            default:
                fill(0, 255, 13); // pink so I can see the undefined thingy.
        }
rect(i*(width/themap.length),f*(height/themap[i].length),themap.length*(width/themap.length),themap.length*(height/themap[i].length)); //displays in khanacademy. Just look at the link, it will make more sense. 
    }
}
};
```

basically, the advantage for this method is that a coordinate system is in place and also, a quick way of displaying the different colors.

You could probably be creative with a createElement() instead of rect and switch the fill statements with image srcs.

In order to access point (0,0) all you have to do is type `hunger_map[0][0] // returns 0` point 0,0 is at the top left corner of the grid.

Oh, and also, it does not have to numbers. replace the numbers(and the commas in between) with just one long string. But, in my opinion, It's harder to read.